# Ubuntu Server 12.04 + Webmin, add hard drives to raid 6

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, raid, webmin

the subject may already discussed, if this is the case, a reference would be much appreciated because I really searched and never found real answers to my questions.

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server installation, I manage 50% with Webmin and the rest from the command line. I have a few hard drives in RAID 6. I would like to grow the cluster by adding 5 other hard drives without losing my data. Is this possible? And if so, is it possible to handle all via Webmin?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webmin has nothing for managing RAIDs of any type - only volumes and volume groups through LVM or partitions through `parted`. Your best bet is to consult the documentation of your RAID setup (hardware or software) for what may be entailed by trying to grow your RAID volume set. Given the distributed parity configuration of RAID 6, it may take a while to add 5 new drives to the set.

Comment: ok thank you, I was looking for the easy solution. But I read a lot and it is possible to do from the command line. However, for non knowledgeable in linux,  it becomes a little more difficult. Maybe I'll create scripts to make it easier for certain people.

thank you very much

Comment: Do you know in this case a tool that can be managed remotely via http / web interface?

Comment: @NeurOSick Sorry, no I don't.

Comment: Digression, Webmin has a module that allows you to manage different types of RAID, but not to increase the array. ;) Otherwise thank you for your help friend.